# App not displaying data after Ensembles Merge

Tags: ensembles

I have an iPad app that uses Ensembles; it uploads the CD to iCloud, but when I test it on a 2nd iPad, the app starts, but the sync'd data in iCloud is not downloaded (I can see the data in the 2nd iPad's iCloud Manage Data).

This is the log from Verbose logging:

> 2015-12-24 09:39:50.352 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376]
>   [Crashlytics] Version 3.4.1 (92) 2015-12-24 09:39:50.546
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376]
>
> ensembleStatus: 1 2015-12-24 09:39:51.219
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDEICloudFileSystem
>   repairEnsembleDirectory:completion:] line 176: Checking if repairs are
>   needed in iCloud Drive 2015-12-24 09:39:51.274
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   retrieveRegistrationInfoForStoreWithIdentifier:completion:] line 724:
>   Retrieving registration info 2015-12-24 09:39:51.315
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] __77-[CDECloudManager
>   retrieveRegistrationInfoForStoreWithIdentifier:completion:]_block_invoke_2
>   line 743: Downloading file at remote path:
>   /BookInventoryMgr/stores/1778720D-A5E8-472E-8E62-CD9FE8C31D94-215-0000000391179BA0
>   2015-12-24 09:39:51.385 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376]
>   -[CDECloudManager createRemoteDirectories:withCompletion:] line 688: Creating remote directories 2015-12-24 09:39:51.629
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   importNewDataFilesWithCompletion:] line 159: Transferring new data
>   files from cloud to event store 2015-12-24 09:39:51.633
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   importNewBaselineEventsWithCompletion:] line 143: Transferring new
>   baselines from cloud to event store 2015-12-24 09:39:51.659
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDEBaselineConsolidator
>   consolidateBaselineWithCompletion:] line 65: Consolidating baselines
>   2015-12-24 09:39:51.667 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20451]
>   __61-[CDEBaselineConsolidator consolidateBaselineWithCompletion:]_block_invoke line 76: Found
>   baselines with unique ids: (
>       "092431DC-4576-4062-9A15-6B2ED4318BBA-215-00000003A933FF2D" ) 2015-12-24 09:39:51.677 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20451]
>   __61-[CDEBaselineConsolidator consolidateBaselineWithCompletion:]_block_invoke line 108: Baselines
>   remaining that need merging: (
>       "092431DC-4576-4062-9A15-6B2ED4318BBA-215-00000003A933FF2D" ) 2015-12-24 09:39:51.679 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376]
>   __61-[CDEBaselineConsolidator consolidateBaselineWithCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 line 131: Finishing
>   baseline consolidation 2015-12-24 09:39:51.680
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   importNewRemoteNonBaselineEventsWithCompletion:] line 127:
>   Transferring new events from cloud to event store 2015-12-24
>   09:39:51.771 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20420] -[CDEEventIntegrator
>   integrate:] line 311: Integrating new events into main context
>   2015-12-24 09:39:51.779 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20420]
>   __32-[CDEEventIntegrator integrate:]_block_invoke line 329: Baseline has changed. Will carry out full integration of the persistent store.
>   2015-12-24 09:39:51.813 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376]
>   -[CDECloudManager exportDataFilesWithCompletion:] line 344: Transferring data files from event store to cloud 2015-12-24
>   09:39:51.821 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   exportNewLocalBaselineWithCompletion:] line 332: Transferring baseline
>   from event store to cloud 2015-12-24 09:39:51.828
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   exportNewLocalNonBaselineEventsWithCompletion:] line 320: Transferring
>   events from event store to cloud 2015-12-24 09:39:51.833
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 584: Removing outdated
>   files 2015-12-24 09:39:51.836 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376]
>   -[CDECloudManager removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 603: Baseline files in cloud: {(
>       "0_092431DC-4576-4062-9A15-6B2ED4318BBA-215-00000003A933FF2D_1778720D.cdeevent"
>   )} 2015-12-24 09:39:51.836 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376]
>   -[CDECloudManager removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 604: Aliases for baseline files in store: {(
>       "0_092431DC-4576-4062-9A15-6B2ED4318BBA-215-00000003A933FF2D.cdeevent",
>       "0_092431DC-4576-4062-9A15-6B2ED4318BBA-215-00000003A933FF2D_1778720D.cdeevent"
>   )} 2015-12-24 09:39:51.837 BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376]
>   -[CDECloudManager removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 605: Baseline files to remove: {( )} 2015-12-24 09:39:51.839
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 612: Event files in
>   cloud: {( )} 2015-12-24 09:39:51.839
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 613: Aliases for event
>   files in store: {( )} 2015-12-24 09:39:51.839
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 614: Event files to
>   remove: {( )} 2015-12-24 09:39:51.841
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 620: Data files in
>   cloud: {( )} 2015-12-24 09:39:51.841
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 621: Data files in
>   store: {( )} 2015-12-24 09:39:51.842
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 622: Data files to
>   remove: {( )} 2015-12-24 09:39:51.842
>   BookstoreInventoryManager[285:20376] -[CDECloudManager
>   removeOutdatedRemoteFilesWithCompletion:] line 635: Removing cloud
>   files:

This all looks normal to me;  The populated CD store doesn't appear to be on the 2nd device (I did a MR_findAll, but nothing was returned).

What do you suppose is wrong?

Comment: Some things in the log make me think you may be mixing versions of Ensembles on different devices. Do they all have the same version? Ensembles v1 and v2 don't mix.

Comment: Yes, they all have v1...I loaded the app from XCode... is there something else I need to add to the devices specifically?  (Didn't see anything in the 'Book' regarding this).

Comment: Are you logged into the same iCloud account on both devices?

Comment: Yes... same id on both... I updated my avatar on my Mac and it's the same on both iPads...

Comment: In this Ensembles code:
`- (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = notif.object;
    if (!self.eventStore.containsEventData) return;
    if (context == self.eventIntegrator.managedObjectContext) return;
    
    // Check if this context includes the monitored store  
    NSPersistentStore *monitoredStore = [self monitoredPersistentStoreInManagedObjectContext:context];
    if (!monitoredStore) return; //  <---- this statement IS executed`  
    
*context* is NOT a monitored store (I use *defaultContext* throughout my app).  So, how do I fix this?

Comment: That is correct. Ensembles will only monitor a context that saves directly into the persistent store on disk. If you are using Magical Record, that is probably a background context. Note that such a background context may save at a later time. You have to make sure the background context is fully saved to disk when you quit or go to the background.

Comment: So, do I change all my references from "defaultContext" in my app to "context"?  or should I make "context" the same as  (equal to) "defaultContext" before I make any Ensembles calls?

Comment: Best to take a look at the MagicalRecord example app in the Ensembles source code. It shows how to handle the background context. In short, you need to merge changes into BOTH the contexts when merges happen. And it is best to force the background context to save going to the background, before you call processPending... on the Ensembles.